# Share a feed post using http://getstream.io/

Tags: getstream-io

By using http://getstream.io/ I am able to load all feeds and feeds by user also able to like or comment on feed post. Now wanna achieve sharing of feed post. How should I do it?

Following is the point that I have in my mind

- insert the existing feed again for the user who wanna share

Is there any other way provided by http://getstream.io/ to share the post?

Comment: question is a bit too generic, you probably need to use the `to` targeting field (check https://getstream.io/docs)

Comment: Followed the docs, Now question is how you know that its shared feed?